# Remove simetrics tuples in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, tuples

I'm using MS SQL Server 2005 Express. I have the table INVENTORY, and I want to retrieve all the pairs of product which have the same color (for example).

So, I have the following query:

```
SELECT I1.ProdId,I2,ProdId FROM Inventory AS I1,Inventory AS I2
WHERE I1.Color=I2.Color
ORDER BY I1.ProdId
```

This will return some like this:

```
ProdId|ProdId
-------------
   1  |  2
   1  |  3
   2  |  1
   2  |  3
   3  |  1
   3  |  2
```

I need the symetric tuples (like  1-2, 2-1) shows only one tuple.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT I1.ProdId,
       I2,ProdId 
FROM Inventory AS I1,
     Inventory AS I2
WHERE I1.Color=I2.Color
  AND (
       -- here I get the rows without the symmetric 
       I1.ProdId || '-' || I2,ProdId <>  I2.ProdId || '-' || I1,ProdId 
       OR
       (
          -- here I get the rows with the symmetric but only with the first id 
          -- smaller than the second, so excluding 'duplication'
          I1.ProdId || '-' || I2,ProdId <>  I2.ProdId || '-' || I1,ProdId 
          AND
          I1.ProdId  < I2.ProdId 
       )
      )
ORDER BY I1.ProdId
```

Comment: Thanks! Your query does not work properly, but was of great help. I modified it a little bit and work fine. At the end, it's looks like this: SELECT I1.ProdId,I2.ProdId
FROM peliculas AS P1, peliculas AS P2
WHERE P1.idIdiomaOriginal=P2.idIdiomaOriginal
AND I1.ProdId<>I2.ProdId AND I1.ProdId  < I2.ProdId
ORDER BY I1.ProdId